# Empty string in HTML rendered result from Django/Python

Tags: django

Given

```
siteInfo = \
{
    'appname3': 'MSQuantDynamics11',
    'siteBase': 'http://www.pil.sdu.dk/1',
}
```

in a "urls.py" file.

This works as expected:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$',  direct_to_template,                         \
      {                                                  \
        'template'     : "homepage.html",                \
        'extra_context': { 'siteInfo': siteInfo },       \
      }
    ),
)
```

Why does it not work with the following? (The result of "{{ siteInfo.appname3 }}" in
homepage.html becomes emtpy):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$',  direct_to_template,                         \
      {                                                  \
        'template'     : "homepage.html",                \
        'extra_context': siteInfo,                       \
      }
    ),
)
```

Would it work if "siteInfo.appname3" was changed to something else?

Comment: Why all these backslashes?

Answer (score 11):

Use `{{ appname3 }}` instead of `{{siteInfo.appname3}}`  .

Because key-value pairs `{{appname3}}` can be directly accessible in the template, rather than accessible through `{{ siteInfo.key }}`.

In the first example, you're creating a dict to be passed into `extra_context`, with the key `siteInfo`, and the value being the `dict` `siteInfo`. In the second, you're passing the `dict` `siteInfo` directly.